# No Poker in Las Vegas for awhile?

Tags: casino

I am hearing some scuttlebutt that poker is not reopening in Las Vegas for some time. A friend whom was dealing at a Station Casino says they may not reopen their Poker Rooms for some months yet. I contacted a friend whom I work with at Bellagio whom says MGM is not opening poker right away.

Does anybody know anything about Las Vegas poker? Can anybody tell us what is going on in other poker markets?

Answer (score -1):

I've  been reading on the web (depending on how long the pandemic lasts) that all casinos will eventually be forced, by gaming-law, to remove all the chips from the tables; the same way they got rid of coins from the slot-machines.

Also, no cash will be allowed to pass between hands. All games will be run electronically using credit cards and debit cards with pay-outs given by slot-machine paper slips.

All players and staff must wear masks and only socially distanced dealers will touch the cards.

Like I said, depending on how long the pandemic lasts will determine how desperate the casino owners and government get to re-open and provide the safest possible environment for everyone.

Here's  a YouTube  news channel: [**Not Leaving Las Vegas**](https://youtu.be/vMhEnS-MeOM) . As far as poker is concerned this image popped up. Also, if you're interested drop the [**poker chatroom**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2185/poker)

[image]